# Creating a GUI C++ application with Visual Studio. How should I use a Text Static control?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi

I created a simple Visual C++ project with Visual Studio 2017 (Windows Desktop -> Windows desktop application)

I'm creating my Main window and, as I understand, it's not a "Dialog" since it's the main window. Now I want to add a Text Static Control on it, and I'm a little bit confused because [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/about-static-controls) says

> [...] they are designed for use in dialog boxes, where the system
>   standardizes their behavior [...]

Am I missing something here ? We shouldn't use text on the main window ? I don't want my program to display an empty window and then open a Dialog in which I display my text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static controls are windows and it is perfectly fine for your main window to contain such child windows containing static text.

Another option is to implement WM_PAINT handler in your main window and draw that static string there, so without any additional windows.